# Flutter, prevent the keyboard from showing once the time is entered

Tags: flutter

I would like to prevent the keyboard from showing once the time is entered, how could I do it?

[image]

### Updated

I tried using `FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();` and it works for the first try, but it doesn't for the second one. It's kinda weird. Look at this.

[image]

The first works, the second doesn't work, but the third works, also noticed that the keyboard show up even before than the TimePicker is showed. (Sorry for my bad english)

this is the code;

```
  TextEditingController _startTime = TextEditingController();

  Widget _createTimePicker(String text, TextEditingController controller) {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(
            text,
            style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 15),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 10,
          ),
          TextFormField(
            validator: (String value) {
              if (value.isEmpty) {
                return 'Es necesario especificar una hora.';
              }
            },
            controller: controller,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
                border: InputBorder.none,
                fillColor: Color(0xfff3f3f4),
                filled: true),
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.of(context).push(
                showPicker(
                  context: context,
                  value: _time,
                  onChange: onTimeChanged,
                  is24HrFormat: true,
                ),               
              );
              FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  TimeOfDay _time = TimeOfDay.now().replacing(minute: 30);

  void onTimeChanged(TimeOfDay newTime) {
    setState(() {
      _time = newTime;
      _startTime.text = _time.format(context);
    });
  }
```

Comment: That is by design.  Notice that the slider does not change the minutes?  You need the keyboard there if you expect to be able to change the minutes.

Comment: I can change the minutes just by clicking in it

Comment: Show us your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy paste run 2 full code below 
Solution 1: Quick fix for current code 
You can use `Future.delayed` and `FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus.unfocus`

```
onTap: () async {
            Navigator.of(context).push(
              showPicker(
                context: context,
                value: _time,
                onChange: onTimeChanged,
                is24HrFormat: true,
              ),
            );
            await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 50), () {
              FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus.unfocus();
            });
          })
```

Solution 2: Assume you do not need keyboard to show up all the time
You can use `GestureDetector` wrap `TextFormField` and set `enable` to `false`

```
GestureDetector(
            onTap: () async {
              Navigator.of(context).push(
                showPicker(
                  context: context,
                  value: _time,
                  onChange: onTimeChanged,
                  is24HrFormat: true,
                ),
              );
            },
            child: TextFormField(
              enabled: false,
```

working demo 1

[image]

working demo 2

[image]

full code 1

```
import 'package:day_night_time_picker/lib/daynight_timepicker.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  TextEditingController _startTime = TextEditingController();
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  Widget _createTimePicker(String text, TextEditingController controller) {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(
            text,
            style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 15),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 10,
          ),
          TextFormField(
              //enabled: false,
              validator: (String value) {
                if (value.isEmpty) {
                  return 'Please enter some text';
                }
                return null;
              },
              controller: controller,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  errorStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
                  border: InputBorder.none,
                  fillColor: Color(0xfff3f3f4),
                  filled: true),
              onTap: () async {
                Navigator.of(context).push(
                  showPicker(
                    context: context,
                    value: _time,
                    onChange: onTimeChanged,
                    is24HrFormat: true,
                  ),
                );
                await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 200), () {
                  FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus.unfocus();
                });
              })
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  TimeOfDay _time = TimeOfDay.now().replacing(minute: 30);

  void onTimeChanged(TimeOfDay newTime) {
    setState(() {
      _time = newTime;
      _startTime.text = _time.format(context);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Form(
          key: _formKey,
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              _createTimePicker("", _startTime),
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {}
                },
                child: Text('Submit'),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

full code 2

```
import 'package:day_night_time_picker/lib/daynight_timepicker.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  TextEditingController _startTime = TextEditingController();
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  Widget _createTimePicker(String text, TextEditingController controller) {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(
            text,
            style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 15),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 10,
          ),
          GestureDetector(
            onTap: () async {
              Navigator.of(context).push(
                showPicker(
                  context: context,
                  value: _time,
                  onChange: onTimeChanged,
                  is24HrFormat: true,
                ),
              );
            },
            child: TextFormField(
              enabled: false,
              validator: (String value) {
                if (value.isEmpty) {
                  return 'Please enter some text';
                }
                return null;
              },
              controller: controller,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  errorStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
                  border: InputBorder.none,
                  fillColor: Color(0xfff3f3f4),
                  filled: true),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  TimeOfDay _time = TimeOfDay.now().replacing(minute: 30);

  void onTimeChanged(TimeOfDay newTime) {
    setState(() {
      _time = newTime;
      _startTime.text = _time.format(context);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Form(
          key: _formKey,
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              _createTimePicker("", _startTime),
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {}
                },
                child: Text('Submit'),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After set time to TextInput or on confirm time select, call this `FocusScope.of(context).unfocus()` function.

```
  // update your function
  void onTimeChanged(TimeOfDay newTime) {
    FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
    ...
  }
```

and,

```
  TextFormField(
      readOnly: true,
      ...
  )
```

Comment: It works for the first try, but it doesn't for the second one, I updated the post with some more details of what's happening, thanks for your reply!

Comment: I tried it, but it seems that I'm still having the same issue

Comment: Due to I set `enabled` as `false` I can't now use the `onTap()` function

Answer (score 0):

on the callback function of the time selection dismiss the keyboard
FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();

Comment: It works for the first try, but it doesn't for the second one, I updated the post with some more details of what's happening, thanks for your reply!

Answer (score 0):

if this field is only editable through the time picker, you can make the text field read-only by setting its attribute

```
readOnly: true
```

if the field can be edited by keyboard, then you can await for the dialog result and then call

```
FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(new FocusNode());
```